# R purrr extracting multiple items from a list and converting to a data frame

Tags: r, purrr

I am currently learning `purrr` in R. I have code which does the following

- Uses the `pysch` package in r to get the mean, SD, range etc from a list of questions
- Returns those statistics in a single data-frame where the list item is added to the table as a column. In the case below its schools.

Below is an example where I'm about 90% there i think. All i want to do is add the names of the schools to the dataframe as a column  so as to be able to chart them afterwards. Can anyone help? The method below loses the names as soon as the `bind_rows()` command is run

```
library(lavaan)
library(tidyverse)

# function pulls the mean, sd, range, kurtosis and skew
get_stats <- function(x){

  row_names <- rownames(x)
  mydf_temp <- x %>% 
    dplyr::select(mean, sd, range, kurtosis, skew) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2) %>% 
    filter(complete.cases(.))

  mydf_temp
}

# Generate the data for the reproducible example
mydf <- HolzingerSwineford1939 %>% 
  select(school, starts_with("x")) %>% 
  psych::describeBy(., group=.$school, digits = 2) 


# Gets the summary statistics per school
stats_summ <- mydf %>% 
  map(get_stats) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `.id` argument from `bind_rows`

```
mydf %>%
     map(get_stats) %>%
     bind_rows(., .id = 'group')
```

Using a reproducible example with `iris` dataset

```
mydf <- iris %>%   
           psych::describeBy(., group=.$Species, digits = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, This is exactly what i was looking for